# Is there a way to open native mobile apps on a particular screen from the browser (eg chrome)?

Tags: angular, share, deep-linking

I have website (angular 7) which has a share an image option on whatsapp(as a message), facebook(as a status), twitter, insta (as a post). The website should open these apps on a new tab if its from a PC. But when it is used on mobile (chrome on mobile) it should check if the device has the app installed and open the app on a particular screen. Something just like deep linking. It might sound gibberish or might be a duplicate question. Any help here would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use navigator [Web Share API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share) for that

```
if (navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
      title: 'Web Fundamentals',
      text: 'Check out Web Fundamentals — it rocks!',
      url: 'https://developers.google.com/web',
  })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deep Linking support is implemented by the app owner, so in this case it is FB, Instagram and Twitter that are responsible for allowing deep linking into their apps.

Therefore, it is not a good flow for third party websites to try and deep link into such apps. You should implement deep link to your own app, if you have one, or redirect the user the the mobile-web version of FB\Twitter\Instagram. When the user will reach that mobile web, FB\Twitter\Instagram will be able to deep link him successfully (if that's what they want) using a banner or a button on screen (you often see the banner with "continue in app").

What I'm trying to say is that you shouldn't try to deep link into someone else's app - they may change the deep link method (URI Schemes, Universal Links, etc) and you will remain with a broken link.

Furthermore, both iOS and Android does not allow you to check if an app is installed, so you'll need to have some mechanism to try and deeplink and then on failure redirect to somewhere else - and it does not always work on all platforms and browsers.

Therefore I suggest redirecting users to the mobile web versions of FB\Twitter\Instagram.